# This css is not working on the footer element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a gradient to an image which is being set as a background image of a footer element.I have confirmed that the motif.png exists in the same folder as the html file is.  I have a sample html page as follows . [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/17kzcbay/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>this is a dummy title</title>
    <style>
      #footer {
          color:#777;
          display:block;
          vertical-align:bottom;
          background:  #3c8dbc !important;
          background-image: url(motif.png) repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3c8dbc), color-stop(1, #67a8ce)) !important;
          background-image: url(motif.png) repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #3c8dbc, #67a8ce) !important;
          background-image: url(motif.png) repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%) !important;
          background-image: url(motif.png) repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#67a8ce, #3c8dbc) !important;
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#67a8ce', endColorstr='#3c8dbc', GradientType=0) !important;
          color: #fff;
          border-top:#252525 5px solid;
          z-index:101;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>You are welcome</p>
  </body>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <p>Dummy Para</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <p>Copyright Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</html>
```

I am now wondering why the image along with the background gradient is not being applied to it. Only the color is applied. Some help is needed, please.

**Update**
As per Tyler's recommendations, I have done this

```
  background: url(motif.png) repeat #3c8dbc !important;
  background:  -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3c8dbc), color-stop(1, #67a8ce)) !important;
  background:  -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #3c8dbc, #67a8ce) !important;
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%) !important;
  background:  -o-linear-gradient(#67a8ce, #3c8dbc) !important;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#67a8ce', endColorstr='#3c8dbc', GradientType=0) !important;
```

the gradient is applied , but the image is not applied.

Comment: Well for starters you do have two `color` rows in your CSS

Comment: By declaring a separate `background-image` entry for each gradient, you are telling the CSS to ignore the previous entries. You need to combine all your gradients into one property. Right now the only one that is being honored is the one for Opera.

Comment: @TylerH : can you please let me know how should i do that please ? any examples would help me do I am planning to do .. thanks

Comment: @MikeK i have done that as well but the issue is still persisting. That was a mistake from my side which i have since corrected. thanks ..

Comment: Put the image itself in its own `background-image` property, and then do four more for the gradients.

Comment: @TylerH : Done that.. but its still not working. I have updated the question ..thanks

Comment: You also have to start directions with the keyword `to`, and `center` is not a valid direction. You can have top/bottom, and then left/right. Finally, check to make sure you also have an un-prefixed property for `linear-gradient` as well; all major browsers have supported it w/out prefixes for multiple versions now.

Comment: Try a [CSS Genrator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Why is your `footer` **outside** the `body` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```css
      #footer {
        color: #777;
        display: block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        background: #3c8dbc;
        background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%);
        background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3c8dbc), color-stop(100%, #67a8ce));
        background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%);
        background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png"), -o-linear-gradient(top, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%);
        background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%);
        background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c8dbc 0%, #67a8ce 100%);
        filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3c8dbc', endColorstr='#67a8ce', GradientType=0);
        color: #fff;
        border-top: #252525 5px solid;
        z-index: 101;
      }
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Dummy Para</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Copyright Paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```